# How to set an onClick attribute that would load dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

This code is suppose to add an onClick event to each of the `a` elements, so that clicking on the element would load the content of the page dynamically into a DIV.

Now, I got this far - It will add the onClick event, but how can I load the dynamic content?

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {
  $("li.cat-item a").each(function (i) {
      this.setAttribute('onclick','alert("[load content dynamically into #preview]")');
  });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of the alert you'll need to call a function to perform some ajax request to retrieve the dynamic content.

Comment: Yes, that was the objective of my question :) How should the AJAX code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {
  $("li.cat-item a").click(function (e) {
      $('#this-is-your-target-div').load(this.href);
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

See the documentation for jQuery ajax functions here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('li.cat-item a').bind('click', function (e) {
    $('#preview').load($(this).attr('href'));

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

There is an extensive amount of AJAX functions in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.cat-item a").click(function() {
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
        $("#preview").html(data);
    });
});
```

Does an AJAX request using `$.get` which is more easier to read imho to the `href` attribute of the clicked element, and puts the retrieved data into the div `preview`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('div.container').html(htmlString);`

where `htmlString` is the html code of the content you want to place inside the `div` with class `container`

Comment: I would like to use the href as the output, is that possible with that method?